# Как очистить кэш crosswalk Android?

Tags: android, webview

Приветствую ! Как очистить кэш crosswalk Android ? Вот что я до сих пор перепробовал:

```
public void aaaa(){

    mXWalkView.clearCache(true);
    deleteDatabase("webview.db");
    deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");

    Method ___getBridge;
    try {
        ___getBridge = XWalkView.class.getDeclaredMethod("getBridge");
        ___getBridge.setAccessible(true);
        XWalkViewBridge xWalkViewBridge = null;
        xWalkViewBridge = (XWalkViewBridge)___getBridge.invoke(mXWalkView);
        XWalkSettings xWalkSettings = xWalkViewBridge.getSettings();
        xWalkSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        xWalkSettings.setCacheMode(LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        xWalkViewBridge.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(false);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    } else
    {
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr=CookieSyncManager.createInstance(LoginActivity.this);
        cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
        cookieSyncMngr.sync();
    }

}
```

Данный метод вызываю в onCreate, onStop, ...